# Carbon - standardising datetime

Tags: php, laravel, csv, php-carbon

I am working on some data migration process, with consists of loads of CSV's

The problem I'm facing now is that the data file I am working with has 2 columns, namely "date" and "time". Now, date itself doesn't have a problem. My "time" column can come in any format, i.e. `H:i`, or `H:i:s`. Regardless of the format, I want my output to be `d/m/Y H:i:s`, and to just append 00 if seconds is not given.

Carbon's createFromFormat requires me to specify what my input format is, which I can't. Currently what I am doing is using Excel to split my CSV files into different files according to the time format, then import them separately, but it's taking too much time.

I can't seem to find a function that allows me to do this either:

```
if(getSecondsFromTime){
  Carbon::createFromFormat($string, 'd/m/Y H:i:s');
}else{
  Carbon::createFromFormat($string, 'd/m/Y H:i');
}
```

Does Carbon/PHP Datetime has a function that I am unaware of that can do this? Or do I have to resolve to regex to do what I need?

Answer (score 1):

If you replace your `/` with `-` then `Carbon::parse` will work:

```
$t = '05/10/2017 18:00';
$c = Carbon::parse(str_replace('/', '-', $t));
```

Comment: I was hoping that Carbon has a function instead of resorting to regex